# How to update template on @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

## Code

I have the following code. I want to update the `results-box` with a random selected choice. How would I update the template on a `@click` event.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button @click="getDecision()" class="ui primary button">Discover</button>
    <p id="results-box"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "SlapButton",
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    methods: {
      getDecision: function () {
        var decisions = [
          "choice 1",
          "choice 2",
          "choice 3",
          "choice 4",
          "choice 5",
          "choice 6"
        ]
        var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * decisions.length) + 0);
        var randChoice = decisions[randNum];
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

## Question

When the user clicks on the button `getDecision()` is called and it selects a random choice from the the `decisions` array. How do I display this random choice `randChoice` within the `p` tag `#results-box`.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/6/)  <sup>and [another micro example](https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/7/)</sup>

Basically. You'll need a variable that will hold the `randChoice` once you define this variable inside `data (){}` object, just give it the value inside your method like this:

```
export default {
  name: "SlapButton",
  data() {
    return {
      randomChoice: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDecision: function () {
      var decisions = [
        "choice 1",
        "choice 2",
        "choice 3",
        "choice 4",
        "choice 5",
        "choice 6"
      ]
      var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * decisions.length) + 0);
      this.randomChoice = decisions[randNum];
    }
  }
}
```

Now just show this data in your element like this:

```
<p id="results-box"> {{randomChoice}} </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following code and please elaborate if this doesn't work:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button @click="getDecision" class="ui primary button">Discover</button>
    <p id="results-box">
      {{choice}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    name: "SlapButton",
    data() {
      return {
        choice: '',
        decisions = [
                  "choice 1",
                  "choice 2",
                  "choice 3",
                  "choice 4",
                  "choice 5",
                  "choice 6"
                ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getDecision() {
        var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.decisions.length) + 0);
        this.choice = this.decisions[randNum];
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I got this error message in the console `Property or method "choice" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`